# Select if else in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I encountered a problem to select and change name of columns based on specific condition. For example, if I have a table A which has `name`, `date`, `value` attributes where:

```
name    |date         |value
iphone  |2015-05-01   |1
ipad    |2015-05-09   |3
ipod    |2015-05-20   |6
```

Now I want to select this table satisfy condition that if `name` is not equal `samsung`, `nokia` so it should assign to `apple` and value should be sum if they are in the same month. For example, this table will show the result:

```
name    |date        |value
apple   |2015-05     |10
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the idea : you can use aliases in the group by clause in mysql, but if the alias is equal to a column name, I guess you'll have some problems.

```
select 
       case when name in ('samsung', 'nokia') then name else 'apple' end as name1,
       EXTRACT( YEAR_MONTH FROM date)  as date1,
       SUM(value) as value
from table1
group by 
  name1,
  date1
```

see [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3478c/3)